# Mysql выполнить Insert если ли нет записи с такими же данными

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с 3-я полями:

1. a PK AI,
2. b,
3. c,
   Задача что бы в таблице не было записей с одинаковыми полями b и с при взаимодействии с ней

INSERT INTO tbl (b, c)
set b = 123, c =123 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = 123 AND elem_id = 123;

Comment: Это отчет о ваших подвигах или вы просто забыли написать вопрос? кто вам запрещает сделать Unique на 2 поля?(b+c)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, вопрос, как мне этого добиться ?
Я пытался это сделать вышеуказанным запросом, но увы не вышло...

Comment: Изменить структуру бд. Добавить уникальный ключ и запихнуть в него ваши b и c

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков
Во - первых этого нельзя сделать пока что..
Во - вторых по отдельности нужно  что бы в таблице не было записей с одинаковыми полями b и с

Comment: Тогда изложите таки цели и условия чтобы не устраивать очередные гадания) ODKU работает с ключами а не с обычными полями

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, как сделать Unique на 2 поля?(b+c) только через запрос?

Comment: `create unique index b_c_index on tbl(b, c)`

Comment: Никак... сначало select потом insert. Или unique на каждое поле/ на оба поля

Comment: А что бы запись просто не вставлялась достаточно писать `insert IGNORE into tbl(b,c) values(123, 123)` (при наличии уникального индекса разумеется). А предложение on duplicate изменяет существующую запись, если она есть. И посмотрите внимательно синтаксис insert. вы либо пишите `into tbl(b, c) values(...)` либо `into tbl set b=123, c=123` а не смешивайте два эти стиля